# I can't hide the last column of a Google Sheet using Google Apps scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this sheet that I need to modify using a script as I am producing a large number of sheets and can't do each one manually:

[image]

This is the code I am using that is supposed to hide the last column "AA" from the sheet beside some other things:

[image: code]

Every line is working as expected except the one where I try to hide column AA is producing this error and I've already tried a lot of variations to this line all resulting to this error:

> Exception: Those columns are out of bounds.

Comment: Try to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` command before you hiding column(s).

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet and/or code so we can test it? It's better than blind guessing what the problem and the solution might be.

Comment: used the SpreadsheetApp.flush() before hiding it and it worked, thank you.
how can I mark your answer as the right one?

Comment: It's okay. It's a very common problem and the standard trick.Your feedback and your own answer is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [Yuri Khristich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14265469/yuri-khristich), using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before attempting to hide the last column in the sheet worked.